# Close modal on successful axios post

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried changing the state when you manage to do a successful post without any further success.

### My Post Method

```
 saveOnClick = () => {
    axios.put('http://localhost:8080/lagbevakning/revision', {
      revisionId: 36,
      subscriptionId: 21549450,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        alert("You've sucessfully managed to do that")
        /* here i wish to close the modal */

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
        alert("something went wrong")
    })
  }
```

### my state

```
  state = {
    open: false /* if true, modal is open */
    }
```

### close modal method

`close = () => this.setState({ open: false })`

Any suggestions on how to close the modal on successful axios post would be much appreciated.

Comment: this.setState({open: false});

Comment: Are you receiveing any error? does state stays open after using `close()`? why shouldn't you just call close function inside `then()`?

Comment: when using this.setState({open: false}) i get rendered to the .catch error and the modal doesnt close.

Comment: Before `axios.put`, `const self = this`. Inside the `then`, do `self.close()`

Comment: Replace `function (response) {` with `(response) => {` and then try to call `this.close`. `this` doesn't refer to what you expect when you create a new regular function.

Comment: @Tholle This solved the issue, you legend! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin pointed out, the context would be wrong inside the `then`. So you need to keep a reference of `this` into a separate variable ( or constant ).

Do the following :

```
saveOnClick = () => {
    const self = this;
    axios.put('http://localhost:8080/lagbevakning/revision', {
      revisionId: 36,
      subscriptionId: 21549450,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        alert("You've sucessfully managed to do that")
        /* here */ self.close();
        /* here i wish to close the modal */

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
        alert("something went wrong")
    })
  }
```

Comment: This doesnt quite work.
It makes the  alert("You've sucessfully managed to do that") and gets rendered to the .catch and displays  alert("something went wrong") straight afterwards.
The modal never gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

use arrow function instead of calling with function